# wget unable to establish SSL connection in bash script

Tags: bash, wget

The following command works on the command line:

```
wget --secure-protocol=PFS -O dcm4chee-arc-5.15.1-mysql.zip https://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/files/dcm4chee-arc-light5/5.15.1/dcm4chee-arc-5.15.1-mysql.zip/download
```

However, when I put the exact same line into a bash script (it's inside a function), it results in this error:

> Resolving sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)... 216.105.38.13
>
> Connecting to sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)|216.105.38.13|:443... connected.
>
> Unable to establish SSL connection.

I've even pulled it out of the function to see if that makes any difference, but it doesn't.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A place to start is using `openssl s_client -connect sourceforge.net:443`, which generally provides much better logging around the SSL negotiation than wget. That said, I don't generally advise noninteractive use of wget *at all*; many of its design decisions are oriented around interactive use rather than scripting.

Comment: (that said, you'd probably have the same issues with curl, insofar as the usual cause of SSL negotiation failures when communicating with well-known sites is use of a SSL certificate store that doesn't have the necessary CA cert; environment variables can influence the openssl.cnf file, and thus the CA cert store, in use).

Comment: Putting a line of text in a file and executing that file as a shell script does pretty much exactly the same thing as pasting that line of text at the prompt (modulo some interactive features like aliases etc). I am willing to bet money that there are more differences than this between your working and non-working scenarios.

Comment: How do you run your script? Are you using the same user, or a different user? Do you have a proxy in between and $https_proxy is not set when you run the script? Your problem looks rather environmental (set/unset global vars).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd disagree with you. Wget is specifically designed for non-interactive use. It has clean fallbacks to move from interactive to non-interactive use. We even prevent changing any part of the output to ensure that any scripts running / parsing Wget don't break.

Comment: @darnir, ..."specifically designed for" noninteractive use cases? And yet you have dotfile-based configuration, so scripts can't trust the tool to behave in a consistent way across user accounts, and remote-URL-derived default output names. curl's pipe-centric defaults integrate better with The Unix Way; I understand why some of wget's decisions (ie. deriving output filenames from URLs) make sense in the context of its recursive-mirroring use case, but that single use-case drives enough of the design to make me wary.

Comment: @tripleee and Mihai : believe me, I've copied what was in my script onto the command line and it runs just fine. Additionally, my script ensures that it's being run as "sudo su", which is who the terminal command line runs as. There are no global vars involved at all.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - I tried using the `openssl s_client -connect sourceforgnet.net:443` and I get a response, SSL handshake and SSL-Session information. It was due to this that I added the `--secure-protocol` switch on wget as I read, by default, wget uses TLSv1 only.

BTW : I'm using wget v1.17.1 (native to Ubuntu 16 server)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Since this is the wrong platform to argue about that, I'll stay away. However, if you'd like to debate that point / critique the design decisions, I welcome you on our mailing lists / IRC channel.

Answer (score 0):

Kicking myself ... my IDE had `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top of the file, whereas changing it to simply `#!/bin/bash` made everything work as expected. I thank you all for the responses, crediting @Mihai with direct assistance due to the comment about "environment"